# ggplot2 guide colors shift

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem while trying to create multiple plots with `ggplot2`.
What I am trying to do is create plots of data on top of a `ggmap` object using `stat_summary_hex` and I want all the plots to share the same fill palette.

So what I am doing is I use:

```
ggmap(TAmap) +
  coord_cartesian() +
  stat_summary_hex(aes(x = stop_lon, y = stop_lat, z = timediff, color = timediff),
                   fun = function(x) mean(x), bins = 30, alpha = 0.55,data = Atemp)+
scale_fill_gradient2(low = "green",mid = "lightblue" , high = "red", midpoint = 0)
```

and they all come out with the same colors, my main problem is the scale keeps shifting, for example:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this and keep using `scale_fill_gradient2`?
I don't want to create a unique color scale just for this data.
The plots later will be used to create a video and I want the legend to be consistent.

Comment: You need to specify scale limits.

Comment: @Roland what argument am i missing for that?

Comment: Every continuous scale has a `limits` parameter.

Comment: found it, it seems to work. thank you. if want to post it as a complete answer i would accept.